Present Perfect Continuous + Before + Present Simple vs. Past Perfect Continuous + Before + Past Simple / Which combination to choose?

As an obstetrician, I must say that throughout my career I've known women who have been smoking cigarettes for five or even ten years before they become pregnant and they had healthy pregnancy, carried to term and gave birth to a healthy children.

I'd like to know if this sentence sounds good to you. Should I use had been smoking and became instead?
I've made some research and, as far as I understand, these two examples can be used interchangeably. So, I'd like to know if this is correct assumption.

Had been smoking and became are more logical, but if the obstetrician is being interviewed it sounds natural enough. Even educated people sometimes mix up tenses when speaking off-the-cuff.

@KateBunting You said "...but if the obstetrician is being interviewed it sounds natural enough." I'd like to know if it's grammatical too.

See my answer! When I said it 'sounds natural', I meant that if I heard someone say that in a broadcast interview I wouldn't think they were stupid because they used an odd mixture of tenses.

@KateBunting I've read your answer,  of course! The thing is that I actually wanted to edit my comment but couldn't do that, so I deleted it and posted again. That's why this happened. Sorry for that & thanks a lot!

Leaving out the clause, it doesn't seem correct to me to say I have known women who become pregnant, so I think all the verbs should be in the past tense. Had been smoking - became pregnant - had healthy pregnancies - gave birth.
(NB The plural pregnancies is better because there were multiple women, and it should be gave birth to healthy children.
